# Getting System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known Error while calling external API from AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, api, rest, aws-lambda

I am trying to call external REST API from standalone AWS Lambda function(It is not having any VPC or other services attached to it). When I execute the Lambda function, its returning **System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known**
error. Can anyone help me here how to fix this? REST API and AWS Lambda functions are written in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 possible answers.

1. API Role - Add policy "AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess" and manually adjust the trust relationship:

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"Service": [
"lambda.amazonaws.com",
"apigateway.amazonaws.com"
]
},
"Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
]
}

2. Lambda Role - Add this policy "AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess"
3. Permissions on your API, under settings change it to regional instead of private for a quick test. If this worked than you need to add your VPC endpoints to the private list.